# Are there atoms in the lattice of intermediate logics?

Tags: lo.logic, lattice-theory, universal-algebra, proof-theory, modal-logic

A few days ago I stumbled upon [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4598211/is-it-known-whether-there-are-atoms-in-the-complete-lattice-of-intermediate-logi) on MS. The question is: Does the lattice of intermediate logics have an atom, *i.e*. an element that is strictly stronger than IPC but not strictly stronger than another logic that is itself strictly stronger than IPC? The question has not been answered on MS and I didn't find an answer in any other source too.

Thinking about the question myself I had the idea of finding a systematic way to weaken the sentences an intermediate logic includes in addition to IPC but I couldn't find any way to do so repeatedly in a way that doesn't result in either intuitionistic tautologies or additional sentences intuitionistically equivalent to the sentences I began with. I would appreciate any answer or any proposal about possible ways to go forward with solving the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no atoms.

Assume for contradiction that $L$ is an atom. Since $L$ strictly contains IPC, there is a finite rooted Kripke frame $F$ that does not validate $L$, thus $L$ proves the Jankov–De Jongh frame formula for $F$, let me denote it $\beta^\sharp(F)$. Let $G$ be a finite rooted frame that properly contains $F$ as a generated subframe. Then $L\supseteq\mathsf{IPC}+\beta^\sharp(F)\supsetneq\mathsf{IPC}+\beta^\sharp(G)\supsetneq\mathsf{IPC}$. (The indicated inclusions are strict because $F$ is a model of $\mathsf{IPC}+\beta^\sharp(G)$ that does not validate $\beta^\sharp(F)$, and $G$ is a model of $\mathsf{IPC}$ that does not validate $\beta^\sharp(G)$.)